# How to calculate the distance between group centroids in R (following betadisper in vegan)?

Tags: r

I am wondering what would be the correct code in R to calculate the distance between group centroids? I have used the betadisper function in vegan on a dissimilarity matrix using Bray-Curtis dissimilarities, which gives average distance to centroids within groups, but now I want to calculate the difference between these 2 centroids.

I have tried the dist_between_centroids function in package usedist

```
data(iris)
dist.iris<-vegdist(iris[,1:4],method = "bray") #calculate Bray-Curtis dissim
dist.iris

#avg distance to group centroids
permdisp<-betadisper(dist.iris,iris$Species,type="centroid")
permdisp


library(usedist)
dist_between_centroids(dist.iris,1:50, 51:100) #1:50 = group setosa, 51:100 = group versicolor
```

So, avg distance to centroid for group setosa is 0.04 and for group versicolor this is 0.04 as well. For the distance between group centroids for setosa and versicolor, I get an output of 0.22. Is this then the correct distance between the centroid of group setosa and centroid of group versicolor, or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: After a look at the documentation it seems so. In your place I would compare those results with metrics I am more familiar with (like sum of square intra-group vs sum of square inter-group , and doing a quick by hand calculation of cluster center, average distance intra/inter group).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will indeed try to verify the outcome using another approach